# Cancel fetch with continue request in a custom hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have created a custom hook to fetch data. In that hook I have an async function looking something like this:

```
const useData = () => {
    const [enabled, setEnabled] = useState(true);
    const [data, setData] = useState(false);
    const fetchData = async () => {
        const response = await fetch();
        const data = await response.json();

        while (data.continue && enabled) {
            response = await fetch(data.requestId);
            data = await response.json();
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(enabled);
    }, [enabled]);

    return { data, setEnabled };
};
```

When I call setEnabled(false) from a component it's set to false when the useEffect logs it but it continues to be true in the fetchData function and it never cancels the fetch which I was expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the `fetchData` callback function "captures" the state of the `data` variable when it is first called, and it doesn't know about the new value of `data` when you change it (this is known in React as stale closures). To fix this, you have to use the `useRef` hook instead:

```
const useData = () => {
    const [enabled, setEnabled] = useState(true);
    const [data, setData] = useState(false);
    const isCancelled = useRef(false);
    const fetchData = async () => {
        const response = await fetch();
        const data = await response.json();

        while (data.continue && !isCancelled.current) {
            response = await fetch(data.requestId);
            data = await response.json();
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        isCancelled.current = !enabled;
    }, [enabled]);

    return { data, setEnabled };
};
```